# rosmake android_app_chooser returns error

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I setup my computer following `http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android`, but `rosmake  android_app_chooser` returns error.

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/mechuser/prog/rtm-ros-robotics/android_app_chooser/build.xml:5: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/mechuser/prog/rtm-ros-robotics/appmanandroid/build_app.xml:64: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/mechuser/prog/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/pre_setup.xml:4: Your build.xml file is outdated. Delete it and regenerate it with 'android update project'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11595/rosmake-android_app_chooser-returns-error/) by [keisuke-m](https://answers.ros.org/users/1244/keisuke-m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial rely on the previous version of the android(and obsoleted) sdk

```
$ wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r13-linux_x86.tgz
$ android update sdk -u -o -t "`android list sdk -o | grep "Android API 9" | awk "{ print \\\\\$1; } " | sed 's/-//g'`,`android list sdk -o | grep "SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9" | awk "{ print \\\\\$1; } " | sed 's/-//g'`"
```

Also, I have do downgrade `rosjava_android` repository
hg update ec39ea3fdb22

Then `ant` still produce error but `ant install` works. Should we need to upgrade the wiki tutorial?

---

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2011-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2011-11-02**:
Ok, I have updated the SDK

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-11-02**:
Yes, an update to the tutorial with thew new SDK info would be great.